# Cannot connect to redis instance by using redisson

Tags: java, spring-boot, redis, spring-data-redis, redisson

I am able to connect to a redis instance by using jedis but not by using redisson.

Here is my jedis configuration:

```
@Bean
    public JedisConnectionFactory jedisConnectionFactory(@Qualifier("appRedis") final RedisProperties redisProperties){
        RedisStandaloneConfiguration config = new RedisStandaloneConfiguration(redisProperties.getHost(), redisProperties.getPort());
        config.setPassword(RedisPassword.of(EncodeDecodeUtil.decode(redisProperties.getPassword())));
        JedisClientConfiguration.JedisClientConfigurationBuilder jedisClientConfiguration = JedisClientConfiguration.builder();
        jedisClientConfiguration.usePooling();
        jedisClientConfiguration.readTimeout(redisProperties.getTimeout());
        JedisConnectionFactory jedisConnectionFactory =  new JedisConnectionFactory(config, jedisClientConfiguration.build());
        jedisConnectionFactory.getPoolConfig().setMaxIdle(redisProperties.getJedis().getPool().getMaxIdle());
        jedisConnectionFactory.getPoolConfig().setMinIdle(redisProperties.getJedis().getPool().getMinIdle());
        jedisConnectionFactory.getPoolConfig().setMaxTotal(redisProperties.getJedis().getPool().getMaxActive());
        return jedisConnectionFactory;
    }


    @Bean(name = "appRedis")
    public RedisTemplate<String, List<Object>> redisTemplate(RedisConnectionFactory jedisConnectionFactory) {
        RedisTemplate<String, List<Object>> template = new RedisTemplate<>();
        template.setConnectionFactory(jedisConnectionFactory);
        return template;
    }


Yml:

spring:
  data:
  redis:
    host: redishost.hosting.company.net
    password: mypassword
    port: 10790
    jedis:
      pool:
        max-active: 5
        max-idle: 5
        max-wait: -1ms
        min-idle: 3
    connect-timeout: 30000
    timeout: 5000
```

Redisson Configuration:

```
@Bean
public RedissonClient client(){
    Config config = new Config();
    config.useSingleServer().
            setAddress("redis://redishost.hosting.company.net:10790")
    .setPassword("mypassword");
    RedissonClient client = Redisson.create(config);
    return client;
}
```

I am getting the error:

```
WRONGPASS invalid username-password pair
```

I am trying to use a basic configuration for redisson to do trial and error. I am just setting basic config parameters such as address, password and port

Comment: Did you resolve the issue?

Comment: max-wait: -1ms i think that is the issue

Answer (score 0):

You need to connect by providing username.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).